# Array Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, fstream

I have a problem with the segmentation fault.
Look:

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,i,vector[10001],vectorcopy[10001];
    ifstream in("program.in");
    ofstream out("program.out");
    in>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        in>>vector[i];
        vectorcopy[i]=vector[i];
    }
    return 0;}
```

And the debugger says:
Program recived signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Please, tell me what to do!

Comment: You need to check whether your input file is actually opened successfully - i.e. add error checking.

Comment: run it in a debugger and it will tell you where in the call stack and what line  it seg'd on

Comment: I did see where is the segmentation fault. it is at vectorcopy[i]=vector[i];

Comment: Your program never checks whether any of the operations succeed. It could be failing at any number of points.

Comment: The in file is: 7 1 5 7 4 6 2 9

Comment: Your `for` loop needs to be `for(i = 0 ; i < n; ++i)`. Arrays are zero indexed in C & C++

Comment: Avoid to name variables as stl-classes (vector, string, etc.). Especially because you wrote `using namespace std;`. BTW, avoid this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is (mostly) working correctly, if the input file `program.in` is correct. I suppose your segmentation fault error is caused by:

- bad input
- the lack of input checking in your program

I got no errors with this `program.in` input file:

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Other errors**

I said "mostly" because there are a few other errors in your program. They are not causing trouble (C++ calls this "undefined behaviour") right now, but sooner or later they will:

- for an array of size `n`, indexes start at 0 and end at `n - 1`; when using arrays, do not write your `for` statement like this:

  ```
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  ```

just rewrite it as:

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

- you are not using the `vectorcopy` array
- you are not writing anything to the `program.out` output file

Comment: He is using the vectorcopy array in the for loop

Comment: As long as he doesn't read past `vector[10000]`, nor write past `vectorcopy[10000]`, his code will run fine.